# Vertical/Height scrollbar appears when adding margin-top

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
div.container
```

My CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}    
.container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

I want to use height=100% and DO NOT want to use overflow=hidden.

Which CSS properties I should use above so that I can have EFFECT OF margin-top for container div above which will not create vertical scroll-bar.

Just Imagine:

```
* Body with color red
* A div container in body and I want to see the margin of "x" px on top bewteen body and conatiner
* Color of div container blue
* No scrollbars and No overflow="hidden"
```

Please help

How can I accomplish this? Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html, body {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top:5px;
}    
.container {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

First reset all margin and padding.
`box-sizing:border-box;` means the size of an element will stay the same no matter how much padding you add to it.

You could also use an absolute positioned div for the red bar.

HTML

```
<div class="red-bar"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

CSS

```
.red-bar{ position:absolute; width:100%; height:5px; top:0; background:red; }
.content{ height:100%; background:blue; }
```

Comment: your solution worked for me. I will understand CSS more and your explanation. Stack and people at stack rocks!!! everybody

Comment: actually I was way too fast to declare success. I am still getting scrollbars. May be I am doing something wrong. I ll check

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted with exactly the code above. I mean putting border-size together with padding in body element. However, if I start using margin instead of padding, then I get the scrollbars again. May be I lack css understanding. Hence I can not mark it as correct or not. But definitely an upvote. Thx

Comment: Is there anything going in the red part? If not you could use a border. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Nothing is going/written inside red part

Comment: Are you familiar with the box model? ie. padding vs margin etc. Give these a read if you aren't. Basic idea http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp and this is a bit more advanced but definitely worth wrapping your head around http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is in use `padding-top` insted of `margin-top`

Answer (score 0):

Since your margin is pushing your div upward and than increasing the total height. In css2 the trick you can do is to wrap your container div in another div and float it either left or right. Because a floated element don't push its parent element in general. And then giving it a width of 100%. Then clearing it. The final code look like...

the markup

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="container">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and the style

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin:0;
}    
.container {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.wrap{height:auto;float:left;width:100%;}
.clear{clear:both}
```

Comment: thx for your quick response. Let me try. However for now the solution below worked for me. I will understand CSS more

Comment: Thank you too. actually the first answer is great and already solved your problem. But that answer contains some css3 rules which are not supported by the older browser. That's why I wrote again how did i solve this problem in my case compatible using only css2.